# Visual C++ ODBC SQL Server 2008 - Incorrect Results

Tags: c++, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have been following this tutorial here to attempt to connect to a SQL Server 2008 database using C++ (via Visual Studio 2008):

http://www.tidytutorials.com/2009/08/connecting-to-sql-server-using-c-odbc.html

The test database I am using has four columns and many rows (>10000) and is structured something like this:

```
╔══════════╦═════╦═════════╦════════╗
║ PeriodId ║ PId ║ ZipCode ║  HPI   ║
╠══════════╬═════╬═════════╬════════╣
║   198702 ║   3 ║   35563 ║ 63.984 ║
║   198703 ║   7 ║   24228 ║ 65.54  ║
║   198704 ║   2 ║   23086 ║ 99.84  ║
║   198705 ║   7 ║   23224 ║ 23.84  ║
╚══════════╩═════╩═════════╩════════╝
```

(Data has modified but you get the picture.)

However, when I query a "SELECT TOP 10 * FROM [database]", I only see the first three columns (i.e. not HPI) returned.  Even worse, if I query a specific column - "SELECT HPI FROM [database]", for example, my results as seen in Windows command prompt will all be in gibberish.

Haven't done much to the code from the tutorial itself (aside from server credentials and database-tailored queries) and it seems that others have had luck with it, so I'm a bit stuck.

Comment: reading the comments below your tutorial I saw this as an answer to your question

" struggled with the same for a while. You have to set the project to use the Multi-byte character set rather than Unicode. That will resolve your issue."

Comment: My project is already set to 'Use Multi-Byte Character Set' (under Configuration Properties -> General -> Project Defaults) - that comment was addressing a different error that involved typecasting